# Save edited HTML in Firefox

Tags: firefox, html, editing, save-as

I load a page in Firefox. In the developer panel I edit some content.

I change some contents (some paragraphs, some bullet points) eventually removing some nodes or adding a new one.

I want now to save the edited page so it looks like the original (headers, css, etc.) but the contents replaced (and/or html elements if added/removed).

When I do "save page as" it saves the original source code. I want to save the "newly generated" HTML structure inside the existing code.

In my previous research I have already found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184944/3417978 but as this is a nearly-13 years old answer maybe technology has evolved given all those "parsers" that we nowadays have that did not exist decade and a half ago...

How can I save the "edited page"? Is that old answer still in force?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184944/3417978

Comment: I already saw that answer in my investigation... but I thought that as that is nearly 13 years old, maybe things improved. I'll edit my question to clarify... thanks.

Comment: You're editing the DOM, not the HTML. And even before editing, the DOM may be different than downloaded HTML because it may have been edited by JavaScript. Not to mention that eg. original HTML may not be exactly spec-conformant and DOM will have that "corrected", possibly losing some information.